# "Add to Dictionary" to a specific custom dictionary

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

When right-clicking a "spelling error" I get the option to **Add to Dictionary**, and it always adds to the same one (I'm trying to use two).

How can I select to which dictionary to add the word, or at least - to change which of the two custom dictionaries will be the one that words will be added to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Microsoft: [Add words to your spelling checker dictionary](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/add-words-to-your-spell-check-dictionary-HA010354289.aspx):

> Whenever you check the spelling of a document, you have an option to
>   add a word flagged as a misspelling to a custom dictionary. The
>   default custom dictionary is the dictionary to which the program adds
>   the word when you do this.

To specify the default custom dictionary used for all languages, or for each language that you work in:

1. Open the *Custom Dictionaries* dialog box. [How-To](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/add-words-to-your-spell-check-dictionary-HA010354289.aspx#_Open_the_Custom)
2. In the *Dictionary* list box, do one of the following:

   - To change the default dictionary for all languages, click the dictionary name under All Languages.
   - To change the default dictionary for a particular language, click the dictionary name under the language heading.
3. Click **Change Default**.

The next time that you check spelling, the program uses the default custom dictionaries that you selected.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed it. I was looking at that dialog box (while the default was highlighted, of course) and didn't notice the disabled button right there saying "Change Default"! Thanks again.